# Преобразование типа вектора из uint8 в uint16

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Есть вектор `std::vector<uint8_t> From;`
Он содержит 10^9 элементов

И есть пустой вектор `std::vector<uint16_t> To;`
В который нужно **перенести** значения так, чтобы значения элементов остались прежними.

Как грамотно это сделать?

Comment: Какой критерий "грамотности"? `std::vector` владеющий контейнер, между разнотипными контейнерами данные (внутреннее представление) пачкой перенести не получится. А учитывая базовые типы вроде `uint` перенос сведётся к простому копированию.

Comment: Непонятно, как переносить, чтобы получилось полмиллиарда уинтов, (пары байтов схлопнулись) или чтобы получился миллиард, но распухший в два раза?

Comment: @gbg да - раздутый в 2 раза

Comment: Перенести - никак, только копировать.

Comment: можно написать обертку, что бы она выдавала элементы правильно или при загрузке сразу грузить правильно. так как целевая задача нам не известна, то и решения могут быть самыми плохими.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
To.assign(From.begin(), From.end());
```

Да, это просто копирование. Хороший компилятор вычислит размер вектора `From`, выделит память и скопирует данные.

Сколько понадобится памяти? Давайте обозначим объём вектора `To` за единицу. Тогда объём вектора `From` будет в два раза больше - две единицы. Так как мы копируем, то на время копирования нам понадобятся три единицы памяти.

Можно ли преобразовать `To` во `From` в меньшей памяти? Нет, так как мы хотим чтобы `From` был вектором.

Вектор умеет распределять память только одним способом - запрашивая непрерывный блок памяти из кучи. Этот блок в момент запроса не может содержать данные - технологии типа `realloc` не используются вектором (почему - отдельный интересный вопрос). Так как данных в этом блоке нет, значит они где-то ещё и занимают одну единицу памяти. То есть в момент распределения памяти для вектора нам нужны три единицы памяти: одна для данных, две для нового вектора.

И общий рецепт - если памяти мало, не используйте вектора. Непрерывный блок памяти сравнимый с размерами памяти - зло.

Comment: хорошее решение... и просто, и ничего лишнего, и у компилятора получается векторизовать операции...

Comment: А разве это не просто копирование. Т.е. в какой-то момент времени мы получим 2а вектора и по памяти это неочень хорошо

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, да, это просто копирование. По-другому вашу задачу невозможно решить.